# Efficient way to mix arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

Given a number of different sized Arrays:

```
let allArrays = [ [1, 2, 3], [a, b], [100, 101, 102, 103] ]
```

I want to take the first element from each array, then the second element from each array, and so on:

```
let finalArray = [ 1, a, 100, 2, b, 101, 3, 102, 103 ]
```

My current, naïve solution is to simply loop through `allArrays` until `allArrays.flat()` is empty, building a new array on the way:

```
          let arr = [ [1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b'], [100, 101, 102, 103] ]
          const new_arr = []
          while (arr.flat().length) {
            for (let sub_arr of arr) {
              if (sub_arr.length) {
                new_arr.push(sub_arr.shift())
              }
            }
          }
          new_arr
          // [ 1, 'a', 100, 2, 'b', 101, 3, 102, 103 ]
```

This strikes me a quite inefficient. What would be the best way to go about this?

Edit to clarify what I'm looking for: Some of the arrays can sometimes be thousands of elements long, and the code is run in the frontend, so I'm searching for a method that is *fast*.

Also, the lengths and combinations of lengths vary considerably, so rather than optimizing for a single scenario, I'm looking for a way that will be guaranteed to be reasonably fast no matter how the arrays look.

Comment: Unless you have thousands of values you shouldn't be worrying about efficiency here, that would be [premature optimisation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil). Pick the most readable solution, ["Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good programmers write code that humans can understand."](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Martin_Fowler)

Comment: Arrays don't guarantee order, so you should probably just flatten it an be done with it. It sounds as if you have some other data structure you are trying to emulate with an Array.

Comment: Best by what metric?

Comment: @TylerH I get your point, and realize this Q might be OT

Comment: @leo It would be easy to keep on-topic if you provide a metric for how you measure "best" here. Most/Fewest lines of code? Fewest operations in a single method? Fastest runtime? Anything at all would be a good start...

Comment: @TylerH I tried clarifying the goal now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If arrays are mostly the same length, find max length and iterate over the `arrays`:

```js
let
  arrays = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    ['a', 'b'],
    [100, 101, 102, 103]
  ];
let maxLength = 0;
let result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
  let len = arrays[i].length;
  if (len) {
    maxLength < len && (maxLength = len);
    result.push(arrays[i][0]);
  }
}
for (let i = 1; i < maxLength; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < arrays.length; j++) {
    if (i < arrays[j].length) {
      result.push(arrays[j][i]);
    }
  }
}

console.log(...result);
```

If arrays are of much different lengths, create an auxiliary array with arrays' indices that have at least a given length:

```js
let
  arrays = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    ['a', 'b'],
    [100, 101, 102, 103]
  ];
let arrsToIterate = [];
let result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
  let len = arrays[i].length;
  if (len) {
    result.push(arrays[i][0]);
    if (len > 1) {
      arrsToIterate.push(i);
    }
  }

}
let idx = 1;
while (arrsToIterate.length) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arrsToIterate.length; i++) {
    let arr = arrays[arrsToIterate[i]];
    if (idx < arr.length) {
      result.push(arr[idx]);
    } else {
      arrsToIterate.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
    }
  }
  idx++;
}
console.log(...result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could reduce the arrays and flat later.

```js
let
    arrays = [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b'], [100, 101, 102, 103]]
    result = arrays
        .reduce((r, array) => {
            array.forEach((v, i) => (r[i] ??= []).push(v));
            return r;
        }, [])
        .flat();

console.log(...result);
```